# How to join these values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function setopacity(opa,id){
    //alert(opacity);
    document.getElementById("txt"+id).style.opacity = "."+opa;
}
function setBColor(Bclr,id){
    document.getElementById("txt"+id).style.background = "#"+Bclr;
}

<div class="col-sm-1">
    <input required type="text" value="FF8C66"  class="jscolor form-control input-lg" name="Bclr[]" onChange="setBColor(this.value,<?php echo $row; ?>);" >
</div>

<div class="col-sm-1">
    <input required="required"  placeholder="opacity" value="20" type="number" min="5" class="form-control input-lg" name="opa[]" onChange="setopacity(this.value,<?php echo $row; ?>);" >
</div>
```

Above is my code (part of code) i'm able to set opacity with above code in my style tag in output but its apply to text and background I mean to both. but I want to apply only to background. how I can done this with my code.

I just try this but not able to get result.

```
function setBColor(Bclr,id){
    document.getElementById("txt"+id).style.background = "#"+Bclr+"."+opa;
}
```

And willing to get output like this

```
<li class="drag" thk="1" id="txt1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event);" style="top: 231px; left: 64px; font-family: &quot;BalooPaaji-Regular.ttf&quot;; color: rgb(21, 0, 255); background-color: rgb(21, 0, 255,0.2);">Your Text 1 </li>
```

Update :   `i just want to add these 2 values +Bclr+"."+opa so i can get output like background-color: rgb(21, 0, 255,0.2); this`

Please help me. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: `opacity` is for the entire element. Use another element to show texts, or omit the opacity, and use a semi-opaque background instead ( `rgba(r, g, b, a)` ).

Comment: @Teemu please see my update question i add what output i want , please explain how i can add these value , im new to javascript . hope got help thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link , in my question i just want to add these 2 values +Bclr+"."+opa so i can get output like background-color: rgb(21, 0, 255,0.2); this . hope you got my point now

Comment: What output are you getting right now?

Comment: You need to set `rgba` to utilize the alpha channel, i.e. `.style.background = 'rgba(21, 0, 255,' + opa + ')'; `, where `opa` is `0.2` or any other value between 0 and 1. Notice also the concatenated closing bracket at the end of the expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is what you need:

```
function hexToRGB(hex) {
  return [(hex>>16)&255, (hex>>8)&255, hex&255].join(', ');
}
function setBColor(id, Bclr, opa) {
  const rgb = hexToRGB('0x' + Bclr);
  document.getElementById("txt" + id).style.backgroundColor = "rgba(" + rgb + ", " + opa + ")";
}
```

Usage:

```
setBColor('Footer', 'AA0099', 0.75);
setBColor('Header', 'FFFFFF', 1);
```